# Edge throws undefined error when accessing module variable through eval

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, es6-modules

I can't mimic this in a snippet, but use the following code to reproduce: 
Windows 10 || Edge-version: 42.17134.1.0 || EdgeHTML: 17.17134

I'm using *ES6-modules*

```
import * as variable_name from 'file'


console.log(variable_name); //will return an [object module]
console.log(eval("variable_name")); //returns undefined error 'variable_name is not defined'
```

Chrome works fine this way.

SAMPLE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No transpiler I guess? Then congratulations, you found a bug in Edge!

Comment: Interestingly when using the Edge debugger when you hover over `variable_name` or any import the value hover box opens but is empty. So even the browser itself doesn't seem to expect this behavior. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

You define `variable_name` as a variable value so you should use it without quotation marks. Maybe the syntax rule is not so strict in Chrome so it works fine with quotation marks. You could modify it into `console.log(eval(variable_name));`, then it can work well in both Edge and Chrome.